# Why don't people use sodium silicate to bind fiberglass instead of epoxy?

Tags: materials, material-science, composite

I tried to search for it, but I couldn't find any answer on the subject. I could only find that water glass is normally used mixed with other stuff like sand to make casting molds.

In my mind it would make sense to mix fiber glass with, well, glass.

But if I couldn't find anything about, probably there is a good reason, and if possible, I would like to know it.

Comment: Binders are not resins. Epoxy isn't normally used as a binder, only as a resin. fabrics may be stitched, or fixed with binders such as corn starch, styrene, PVA, or acrylics.

Answer (score 1):

Because it dissolves in water ; aka -water glass.